# Session inserts without an id

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I'm just standing up a new CakePHP 1.3.14 project and something I've never seen before is happening with my database session storage. It seems that the session record is attempting to get stored without an id:

```
SQL Error: 1062: Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'
Query: INSERT INTO `cake_sessions` (`data`, `expires`) VALUES ('<remove for space>', 1328115862)
```

For some reason, it's not even attempting to populate the `id` field. All I'm doing is loading the homepage. The first load, of course, is okay if the table is empty, but subsequent reloads present this message because the initial session record is stored with no id.

Anyone seen this before?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

```
# Relevant settings
Configure::write('Session.save', 'database');
Configure::write('Session.model', 'Session');
Configure::write('Session.cookie', 'CAKEPHP');
Configure::write('Session.timeout', '120');
Configure::write('Session.start', true);
Configure::write('Session.checkAgent', true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the code base had an `AppModel` in which a default whitelist was being created that excluded the id property. Since the `Session` model extends `AppModel`, the property was being ignored. Fun stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have auto_increment set on the primary key field? Or are you using a UUID? If you are using UUID, make sure the field type is CHAR(36) for primary key. Otherwise, just add an auto increment to that field and MySQL will handle adding the field value for the PK.

Comment: This uses Cake's `cake_sessions` table which has a varchar id field. It's part of core, so it's not an error or anything custom.

Comment: Is this relevant to your problem? http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/1450

Comment: Actually...it looks like that might be precisely my problem. Unfortunately, I'm using the latest 1.3, so the bug is supposedly fixed but maybe I can run down more info in Lighthouse. Thanks.

Comment: Is it a fresh install/upgrade? Check the api against your codebase and make sure that what you need is in fact there. I did see the git commit for it, so it SHOULD be there. What are your security settings set to? Sometimes having security.level set to low could theoretically cause this.

Comment: Security is medium and the change in the commit is there. Feels like a config problem, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Do you have sessions set to auto start?